# What is the significance of 2 ganesha in this below picture?

Tags: ganesha

[image]

Found this picture online, why there are two Ganesha in the below picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called Shiva Panchayatana. Meaning Shiva is centered with four others divinities around him. Pancha means 5, they are Ganesha, Vishnu, Devi, Shiva and Surya. The Kula or Istha devata goes in the center. In your image its Shiva Kutumbha (Shiva's family). You can do the same with other four. Meaning, you can make Ganesha or any of the other 4 to be in the center. The upacharas (offerings) start with the surrounding 4 devatas and finally to the one in the center. You can also notice that its not just Ganesh who is double, its Devi as well. Panchayatana culture was attributed to Adi Shankara to break the barriers between various sects. But many scholars think that Panchayatana tradition existed before Adi Shankara. Mahamundeshwari temples attributed as one of the oldest in Bihar is considered to have Panchayatana.

Finally, why two Ganesh and Devi? Because Sakara Shiva (Shiva/Shankara with form) is always worshipped with his family. Esp Devi. Nirakaya Shiva is associated with arupa-rupi form called Linga, in which case the family will not be seen. A quick Google image search "Shiva Panchayatanam" will give you a lot of pictures and good understanding.